# Travis script exit code never fails even when it should

Tags: python, bash, continuous-integration, travis-ci, saucelabs

The script portion of my Travis yml file that looks like this:

```
script:
- ./run_tests.sh
```

The script itself runs some tests on Sauce Labs. If the script fails due to test failures, it still exits with code 0 and the build continues on to pass as well. Why doesn't the script exit with a failure code if a test fails?

When I output the exit code from the end of my script file, I get 0. When I output the exit code in the .travis.yml file immediately after the script command, I get 1:

```
echo $?
0
The command "./run_tests.sh" exited with 0.
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: have you tried runnig script using `-e` bash option? it should exit immediately if any command inside script returns status != 0. see: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Comment: It still returns the same exit codes; I'm wondering if it might be affected by the fact that the run_tests.sh tests run from within an if statement.

Comment: yep, indeed it does, if a process returns exit code 1 running as a condition inside an if (`if <run_test>; then etc...`), the statement will just evaluate to false and `-e` option won't act upon it. i don't know how you're handling the `else` clause but you could try adding an `exit 1` there and see what happens.

Comment: I think I've narrowed this down to something more to do with python itself than Travis... even when I run tests locally and they fail, their status is still 0.

Comment: Yup, it was related to that.. posted my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I realized this was because I'm actually running my tests using unittest.TextTestRunner, and the exit code from those tests is always 0 unless you specifically catch the test failures and exit based on them:

```
ret = not runner.run(test_suite).wasSuccessful()
sys.exit(ret)
```

Comment: what is the `not` doing here? I tried this but its not reporting the correct value for failed tests.